# tkinter is not recognized as a library when importing it on a pycharm project using python 3.x ¿Why?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter, pycharm

if I try to `import tkinter` in my project, pycharm underlines **tkinter** as being a missing library.

When I try to install the library, pycharm suggests to import the '**future**' library instead of the **tkinter** library.  I don't know why.

If I go to the project interpreter window, I cannot find the **tkinter** library after clicking on the install packages button.

On the pycharm terminal, if I try to `pip install tkinter` it returns:

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter*

I get the same result when trying `pip install python-tk`, `pip install python3-tk`, `and pip install tk`.

Does anyone know why this is?

I imported the project from windows into Ubuntu Mint 19.1, I am using interpreter Python 3.7.2.

Please let me know if I can add any more useful info.

Comment: Open your cmd and type `python -m tkinter` and run it. If a window opens without any errors then it means you've working tkinter library, if not then try installing python again as tkinter is build-in library for python.

Comment: Thank you Saad.  `python -m tkinter` returns No module named tkinter.  I will try and reinstall python

Comment: Use this site to install python https://www.python.org/downloads/ to your computer and then in PyCharm  go to `Add Configurations` (Might be in right top corner) from there try to change your interpreter to the python you install from the site. If you're new to PyCharm, I would recommend this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56bPIGf4us0

Comment: Ok, I am watching the video now.  Will try to reinstall python after that.  Will comment this thread after I'm done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling PyCharm, and reinstalling it from the command line.  The previous version I had installed it through the Linux Mint 19.1 Software Manager, and the version installed behaved in very strange ways; for instance it showed a completely different file tree to the one in my machine when trying to setup interpreters.

Here is the command I used, as per JetBrains recommendation:

`sudo snap install [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community] --classic`

Note: I had to install snap first :)

Answer (score 1):

Install it via apt.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Works for me.

Comment: when `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install python3-tk` in pycharm terminal I get sh: sudo: command not found.  Whould I install it outside pycharm?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the regular terminal. (Ctrl + Alt + T in most Linux Mint distros)

Comment: It returns _python3-tk is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04)._

Comment: This solved it for me. As soon as I installed it from a regular terminal, the red squiggles in PyCharm dissapeared and my `tkinter` import started working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

**tkinter** is a built in library in python.

install this package :'**future**' using this command :

```
pip install future
```

now import '**tkinter**' in your project :

```
import tkinter
```

Comment: Thank you Rajkamal.  After installing the future package, Pycharm still underlines tkinter as a not recognized word in 'from tkinter import *'

Comment: Hi Andres, try using "import tkinter" instead of "from tkinter import * "

Comment: Pycharm still marks the library as not available when using import tkinter

Comment: try importing tkinter in python interpreter using ***import tkinter***. If it works then problem is with your pycharm and python interpreter configuration.

Comment: I think using the interpreter outside of pycharm it works: <\br>

`$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> `

Comment: Go to **File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter**. At top, you will see what python interpreter is PyCharm using for current project.

Comment: It says it is using Python 3.7

Comment: I think this article will help : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205820229-GUI-Using-Tkinter